# Using nodegit in Electron app throws "Symbol not found:" errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, electron, nodegit

I build a project in electron and, when I done I want to add git support to app.
I try add this, by adding [NodeGit](https://www.nodegit.org) to my project. 
Simple

```
npm install nodegit
```

And create file git.js with only

```
var NodeGit = require("nodegit");
```

I run script by

```
<script id="git" src="assets/scripts/git.js"></script>
```

unfortunately when I try run my program, I have errors:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _OPENSSL_init_crypto
  Referenced from: /[PATH TO PROJECT]/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _OPENSSL_init_crypto
  Referenced from: /[PATH TO PROJECT]/node_modules/nodegit/build/Release/nodegit.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

[11635:0118/162433.596391:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18047)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[11635:0118/162433.596514:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(12520)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glScheduleCALayerCHROMIUM: unsupported texture format
[11635:0118/162433.596556:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18047)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[11635:0118/162433.596638:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(12520)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glScheduleCALayerCHROMIUM: unsupported texture format
[11635:0118/162433.596677:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18047)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[11635:0118/162433.596702:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(12520)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glScheduleCALayerCHROMIUM: unsupported texture format
[11635:0118/162433.596730:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18047)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[11635:0118/162433.596753:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(12520)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glScheduleCALayerCHROMIUM: unsupported texture format
[11635:0118/162433.596894:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18047)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[11635:0118/162433.596933:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(12520)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glScheduleCALayerCHROMIUM: unsupported texture format
[11635:0118/162433.596964:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(18047)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[11635:0118/162433.597001:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(12520)] [.BrowserCompositor-0x7f996303c600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glScheduleCALayerCHROMIUM: unsupported texture format
```

I try to delete node_modules folder and install npm again. 
I try npm rebuild to. 
When I put "node -v" I have

> V10.15.0

Is any way to fix this issue, or different way to add git support to electron app?

Thanks for answer! :)

Comment: Which Electron version do you use?

Comment: I'm using v4.0.1.